# How do you filter by application name wildcard using logcat command line

Tags: android, command-line, android-logcat

So in Eclipse, you could filter with app:com.foo, and it would get com.foo, com.foo.bar, com.foo.baz, etc...

Is there a way to do this on the command line?

Answer (score 2):

Reference: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html

From the command line, you can filter logcat messages by Tag and Level.  For example

```
adb logcat MyApplicationTag:I *:S
```

Will show all of the messages with the "MyApplicationTag" tag, at INFO level (note the ":I") or above.  The "*:S" silences all other message.

==================================

To show messages from multiple tags:

```
adb logcat MyApplicationTag:I com.foo.bar:I com.foo.baz:I *:S
```

==================================

To accomplish what was originally asked for (filtering via a wildcard specification), you could simply let the shell do the filtering.  Try the following:

```
adb logcat | grep ^./com\.foo*
```

Comment: There are multiple tags within the applications, and I'm interested in everything under the com.foo banner, instead of just the tag alone.

Comment: I did some experimentation to see if I could get a wildcard to work in the Tag (e.g. com.foo.*) but no luck.  The Android docs make no mention of wildcard support as well.  Thus you are stuck with specifying each and every tag individually.  I will put that detail in the answer.

Comment: See my most recent update.  You can accomplish what you want by letting the shell do the filtering.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to give that a shot.

Comment: Nah. I guess I'll just post process it, alternatively it might be because adb logcat defaults to brief logs, which makes the filtering harder.

I'll poke at it again later on. thanks for checking up :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to do this outside of eclipse and you are on a Mac you can do it this way in LogRabbit

```
app CONTAINS[cd] "com.foo"
```

You can find more information here: http://lograbbit.com

[image]

- Full disclosure I am the creator of LogRabbit.*

Comment: Neat, though I need this to work across multiple environments. There are Windows die hards that I'm having trouble getting them to use *nix.

Comment: Ok, I hope you find the solution you need.

Comment: LogRabbit was the golden tip. Never again will I mess around with command line grep regexes and pipelines and sh*. This guy made the tool exactly as I would create it myself: real time logging with easy filters, coloring etc. Totally worth my $10. I'm not its dev btw, just love a solid one-trick-pony devtool.

Answer (score 2):

Yes!

On top of a solution from Tom Mulcahy, you can further simplify it like below:

```
alias logcat="adb logcat | grep `adb shell ps | egrep '\bcom.your.package.name\b' | cut -c10-15`"
```

Usage is easy as normal alias. Just type the command in your shell:

```
logcat
```

The alias setup makes it handy. And the regex makes it robust for multi-process apps, assuming you care about the main process only.

Of coz you can set more aliases for each process as you please. :)

In addition, if you want to set logging levels, it is

```
alias logcat-w="adb logcat *:W | grep `adb shell ps | egrep '\bcom.your.package.name\b' | cut -c10-15`"
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows user(linux has a better way to do it as stated by other people), I've written a simple python script to filter the logcat output by application.

[Link to github](https://github.com/Meowzz95/AndroidLogcatFilter)